# Microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, flipflop, home-automation

Is there any other way of interfacing a push button with a LED but not directly with the micro controller? I would like to operate the LED in both method(push button as well as micro controller signals based on wireless, blue-tooth etc.). Here the no of pin usage is important.

Comment: How does that FlipFlop reduce the number of pins? IMO it just gets in the way. And your spec is too ambiguous to give a good answer. What exactly must happen while the button is pushed? and when it is released again?

Comment: The image, I have shown is a rough diagram of my idea. In detail, if i press the button, flip flop switches the LED on/off based on the previous status of LED. Micro Controller also has to change the status of LED if this button is pressed. And the LED can be operated any way either by Micro Controller Or Push Button

Comment: That makes no sense. You say that if the button is pressed, both the flip-flop *and* the uc toggle the state of the LED. If taken literally, that would leave the state of the LED unchanged. And what does it mean that the LED can be 'operated' the pushbutton? Is it on while the button is pressed?

Comment: -1 The question title needs improvement, and the question is unclear.

Comment: The OP simply doesn't realize what microprocessors can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, but it is quite frankly insane.  Just use two pins on the MCU, one for the switch and one for the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzedqY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>